# IOS callback url not responding anything

Tags: react-native, square

I followed the instruction of react-native-square-pos, it worked perfectly on android but in ios, it did not give any responses after I cancel the transaction or complete the transaction. Is there any solution for this?

```
SquarePOS.configure({
                  applicationId: "",
                  callbackUrl: "posmanagementsquare://callback",
                });
                const amountInCents = getTotalPaymentWithRounding();
                const currency = "JPY";
                const options = {
                  tenderTypes: ["CARD", "CARD_ON_FILE", "CASH", "OTHER"],
                  note: "This note shows up on the transaction",
                  // locationId: "Optionally pass location Id", // only on iOS at the moment
                };
                SquarePOS.transaction(amountInCents, currency, options)
                  .then((result) => {
                    onAlert();
                    setIsPaySuccess(true);
                    const { transactionId, clientTransactionId } = result;
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    if (err.errorCode === "CANNOT_OPEN_SQUARE") {
                      onAlert();
                      setIsPaySuccess(true);
                      return linkSquareRef?.current?.open();
                    }
                    alert(err?.squareResponse?.response);
                    if (err?.squareResponse?.errorCode === "TRANSACTION_CANCELED") {
                      alert("Cancelled");
                    }
                  });
```

Comment: Where is your code? What does the logs tell?

Comment: Sorry for not uploading the code, i just edited. The logs did not tell anything, i have tried to log something in the then and catch, it didn't log anything, i got stuck with is for two days

Comment: From your code, you didn't add enough debug lines. Try to add debug lines in each branch (e.g. inside `.then()` and `.catch()`).

Comment: @Raptor i have tried both, didn't work